# How do I handle Flutter Test - "Could not prepare isolate" error?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I tried to test my flutter project and push to branch.
However when I use

```
flutter test
```

to test my project, this kind of error occurs.

```
hell: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(144)] Could not prepare isolate.
Shell: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/runtime_controller.cc(462)] Could not create root isolate.
Shell: [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(669)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
```

And then, command said for each tests

```
Failed to load "C:/<my_project>/test/widgets/pump_test.dart": Connection closed before test suite loaded.
```

My project works on flutter run.

How can I handle this test issue?